# Transformer didn't work well with tensorflow gradient tape

Tags: tensorflow, transformer-model

I implemented transformer with tensorflow 2.0. The model works well when I train the model with model.fit(dataset)

However, when I train the model with tensorflow.GradientTape and evaluate it, the model yields blank space token for all inputs. Here is my code, and tensorflow version is 2.7.0

```
def loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
  y_true = tf.reshape(y_true, shape=(-1, MAX_LENGTH - 1))

  loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
      from_logits=True, reduction='none')(y_true, y_pred)


  mask = tf.cast(tf.not_equal(y_true, 0), tf.float32)
  loss = tf.multiply(loss, mask)
  return tf.reduce_mean(loss)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  for step, data in enumerate(dataset):
    enc_inputs, dec_inputs, outputs = data[0]['inputs'], data[0]['dec_inputs'], data[1]['outputs']
    
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      logits = model([enc_inputs, dec_inputs], training = True)
      loss   = loss_function(outputs, logits)

    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
```

I think there is no problem with my transformer model code, because it works well with model.fit(dataset). What's wrong with my code?

Comment: I have a similar issue. What are values in `logits` ? In my case, `logits` values are all nan after updating gradients. transformers==4.15.0 and tensorflow==2.7.0

Comment: I checked with tf.reduce_any(tf.math.is_nan(logits)) and it printed 'False' after updating gradients for a couple of times. My logits yield around -0.1 ~ 0.3. I don't know what's going on.